# Change image background opacity in each div when scrolled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wonder how to make the background image change opacity in each scroll position. The background image has a black background with a photo of a person at first section and when user scroll on to the next section the background of the person should changed it's opacity until it becomes white blur white. I used the a background image and set its css `background-size` to `cover` so that it will be always stay on the screen. Now what I did is just insert a div inside each section and adjust its opacity on scroll but it covers entire background.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section active container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="content content-one">
                    <h2 id="content-one__h2" class="">We are</h2>
                    <h2 id="content-one__h2--second" class="blue">PT Freeport Indonesia</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> NOTE: I used jquery fullpage to achieve the fit to screen in every
>   scroll.

Update: Please see [here](http://wearewhatweare.info/) to understand what I'm talking about.
And the actual result should be like below background should be cover the whole screen only opacity changes at the back of the person.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it to fade out? Can you use some sort of box-shadow?

Comment: Not a fade-out I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you shouldn't touch background-size, just adjust the opacity of the container, this case the body; but that would make everything less visible.
So set the image in a div, make it fixed, and adjust the visibility of that.

Something along the lines of:

```
var maxScroll = 1024; //set this to the desired heigth

$(window).on('scroll', function() {  
     var newScroll = $(document).scrollTop(); //save the new value

     $('#backgoundDiv').css('opacity', newScroll / maxScroll);
});
```

Comment: have you check the link I attached on my post?

Comment: I didn't, it wasn't there when I've posted I think

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to the link you posted they set the background color with alpha value:

First div is: `rgba(255,255,255,0.1)`

Second div is: `rgba(255,255,255,0.2)`

Third div is: `rgba(255,255,255,0.3)`

and so on...

Then they scroll down while keeping the big image as `body` background just as you have.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the one who designed the website. I wanted to maintain the image of the person while making it's background change opacity on scroll

Comment: So instead of setting opacity on the divs, you want the image to 'fade' away?

Comment: can you do a simple fiddle? I want the image to adjust its opacity without affecting the person on the image.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: lol me too that's why i went here to ask some help. wait I'll provide an image

Answer (score 0):

In the URL in your question the each individual scrolled section is a div with gradually varying opacity. You will need to do something like that.

Comment: Yeah, by the way I'm the designer of the website. Now, that's a temporary opacity. what I want is that only the background of the image change its opacity not including the person itself. I'm trying to solve this but can't find an elegant solution.